# Not required input layer in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I would like to know how can I use an optional (not required) input layer (used with other input required or not) in a graphical modeler of QGIS.
Obviously, I uncheck "required" in the panel of the input layer, but if I make a geoprocessing in the model that involves a required layer and a not required layer (that will not be selected in the drop down menu in the final interface of the model), the model doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: What tool are you using, so I can reproduce the model

Comment: i'm using "join attributes by location" and "refactor fields" that involve the not required input layer